# How to add memory zone to linux

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel

I'd like to add a new memory zone (ZONE_DMA, ZONE_NORMAL, ZONE_HIGHMEM, etc) to the linux kernel. For example, this memory zone (ZONE_ALTERNATE), will have special properties that will make it desirable to use in certain instances. Imagine having a special DDR DIMM that performs some operations on the data. I would like to be able to use kmalloc to allocate from this zone. Specifically I would like to add this zone to kernel 2.6.32, but current kernels would also be of use.

Are there any resources or ideas on how to implement this?

Comment: From the top of my head, you should make patches on the kernel implementation for your architecture to achieve what you want.

Comment: @NemanjaBoric Yes, kernel patches are assumed. I'm fairly comfortable with kernel development and it's process. I'm looking for resources on what code to modify or more up to date and in depth documentation on the subject. I've searched through kernel Documentation and source, read through *Understand the Linux Kernel 3rd ed* and *Linux Kernel Development 3rd ed* by Love. Both are good resources but lack what I'm searching for or are too far out of date.